# RegExp: Why this regex doesn't match "not starts with" two letter?

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to match a word not starts with "t"

e.g.

```
/^[^t]est$/.test('test') # false

/^[^t]est$/.test('best') # true
```

but when I try to set the length to 2, it doesn't works:

```
/^[^t]{2,2}st$/.test('ttst') # false

/^[^t]{2,2}st$/.test('tbst') # false (should be true)

/^[^t]{2,2}st$/.test('bbst') # true
```

`tbst` only contains one `t` so should not be matched

anyone can explain why? thanks

Comment: See my updated answer for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RegEx is working as written:

```
/^[^t]{2,2}st$/
```

- ^ assert position at start of the string
- [^t]{2,2} match a single character not present in the list below
  Quantifier: {2,2} Exactly 2 times
- t the literal character t (case sensitive)
- st matches the characters st literally (case sensitive)
- $ assert position at end of the string

You also don't need to do {2,2} as that is a range, you can do {2} for exactly 2 matches, or {1,2} for 1 upto 2 matches.

[REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/zB1sB3/1)

This example should serve as a good illustration of what is occurring within that RegEx.

**If you are looking for a solution to:** Match any word that does not start with tt (case sensitive) you can use the following:

```
/^(?!tt)\w+$/
```

[PROOF](https://regex101.com/r/zB1sB3/2)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just want to match exactly starts with two t character, shouldn't I use `[^t]`?

Comment: `/^(?!tt)\w+$/` matches `ttst`, but `/^(?!tt)st$/` doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

```
 ^[t][t]
```

^ assert position at start of the string

[t] match a single character present in the list below

t the literal character t (case sensitive)

[t] match a single character present in the list below

t the literal character t (case sensitive)

Comment: `/^[\\t][\\t]st$/.test('bbst')` returns false, what i doing wrong?

Comment: is st supposed to be literals?

Comment: sorry, i misunderstand the match, it works by reversing the match.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[^t]{2,2}st$/.test('tbst') # false (should be true)
```

No, it shouldn't. `[^t]{2,2}` is saying the same thing as `[^t][^t]`: both atoms match any character but "t".

Comment: How can I match only contains exact 2 `t` character?

Comment: `/^[^t]*t[^t]*t[^t]*$/`

Comment: it works, thanks, but can you explain what that asterisk used for?

Comment: `*` means that the preceding atom matches zero or more occurrences. `^`: Start of line. `[^t]*`: Zero or more characters other than "t". `t` a literal "t".

Comment: @answer /^[^t]*t[^t]*t[^t]*$/ ......THIS IS WRONG! This accepts
"stts" op wants tt to be start of the word!
Try it here! https://regex101.com/

Comment: I am replying to his question in the comments: "How can I match only contains exact 2 t character?" I have taken this to mean exactly two "t"s in the line. This is why I am answering in comments, not in my answer.

Comment: I think Op is asking for literally "tt" and by his first questions.. "tt" at start

Answer (score 0):

The regexp `/^[^t]{2,2}st$/`requires that the first two characters be something other than `t`. Since the first character is `t`, it does not match the string `tbst`.